# How to play the NFS final pursuit efficiently?

Tags: need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005

I am playing the Final pursuit in NFS Most Wanted 2005, after beating Razor.
But my system resources are a bit low. (1GB RAM, 2GHZ).

So i find the pursuit difficult to evade. The game is going dull, the cars are moving slow on the roads and everytime i just get busted.

It is due to the fact that the memory usage for the game is heavy in the final pursuit.
Is there a way to increase the system memory for the game, to play it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [this forum post](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/need-for-speed-most-wanted-graphics-settings.109378/) from 2010 with somebody who is in almost the exact same situation as you. It's worth noting their computer parts include 6GB RAM to your 1GB, as well as 2.4GHZ clock speed to your 2GHZ.

In the forum the best recommendations were to bring the settings to as low as possible, including graphics settings and anti-aliasing. This post is also six years old, it is likely you can upgrade your computer to have better hardware for almost no cost - assuming you haven't already.

From what I can research, there isn't a way to allocate more memory for this specific game for better performance. Your best bet is to upgrade your hardware and lower your settings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your driving; speed breakers and pursuit breakers are a must. By now you'll know how to reach Rosewood. There's a bus station near that you can get on that and wait for 5 min. You'll get a call, and you have to head to the highway which is near the stadium. Now you'll be done with the orange symbol, the road will be open you just have to get in and you'll find a broken and that's it you'll be the most wanted, enjoy!

Comment: The question asks about pc system stuff, not actual gameplay, so this isn't really the answer the asker was after.